# setting $this->data in a method then gets unset

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, controller, this

I am uploading an image with codeigniter, and in the method I am doing the following,

```
if(isset($_FILES['product_image']['name'])) {
            //some setup needed
            $config['upload_path'] = "./media/images/products";
            $config['allowed_types'] = "png|gif|jpg|jpeg";
            $config['max_width'] = 1490;
            $config['max_height'] = 400;
            //make sure the library is running with clean config
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            //do the upload
            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('product_image')){
                $this->data['image_error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->template->build('/admin/products/create', $this->data);
            } else {
                $this->data['image_data'] = $this->upload->data();
                //die(print_r($this->data));
                $this->template->build('/admin/products/create', $this->data);
            }
        }
```

so basically I check to see if there is something in the $_FILES and then upload if there is assigning `$this-data['image_data']` with the upload data along the way. However when I come to process the data i.e. save the filename in a database, I cannot access `$this->data['image_data']` below is how I am trying to use it,

```
if($this->input->post("submit_create") == "Save") {
    die(print_r($this->data['image_data']));
}
```

however I get the following error,

> Message: Undefined index: image_data

why is this I though assigning things to $this made them accessible not just throughout the method but the entire controller?

Comment: When within a class, instantiating variables against $this should indeed allow other methods within the same instance of the object access these variables. Could you post the whole class?

Comment: You can see it here, http://codepad.org/Cpz3EUMV it extends MY_Controller which can be seen here, http://codepad.org/qXffA8v0

Comment: Just looking at the code quickly I'm guessing that `if(!$this->upload->do_upload('product_image')){` is evaluating to be true so the file data is never being instantiated, just a guess

Comment: Paul, that is not the case I can kill the script and view `$this->data['image_data']` after the upload, it seems to go wrong within the `if(submit_post == "Save")` (line 64)

Comment: When are you using the $this->input->post check? I mean, in the first snippet, where you commented out die(print_r..), is it there that the post() check happens? Could you be more clear on where you check for the $this->data array?

Comment: the save happens between line 64 and line 143, within there I check to see if there is any media to save (there should be as the user cannot save without an upload) I check `$this->data['image_data']` on line 125.

Comment: Ehm...yeah...do I have to guess what's between those lines? :/ Is it the same method? Is it inside a succesful do_upload()? Are you unsetting / reinitializing the $this->data array?

Comment: You can see it here, codepad.org/Cpz3EUMV it extends MY_Controller which can be seen here, codepad.org/qXffA8v0

Comment: Ops, sorry, I missed those links. When I get home I'll take a closer look

Comment: Thanks, for not I have solved it by writing $this->data['image'] to the session and then unsetting the session when the save is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think, when you are printing `image_data` at this point in your example:

```
if($this->input->post("submit_create") == "Save") {
    die(print_r($this->data['image_data']));
}
```

You should actually be using `$image_data` instead:

```
if($this->input->post("submit_create") == "Save") {
    die(print_r($image_data));
}
```

Comment: Oops!  Perhaps it's that the CodeIgniter instance hasn't been constructed `$this->CI =& get_instance();` where that `if` statement is running?

Comment: It's inside a controller (OP posted the full code, I missed those links too); and, btw, $this->data is just a class property, it would work anyway in any class (not just the Ci superobject)

Comment: Ah, now I see those links in the comments - thanks! ... I wasn't sure if he was in a helper or library, in which case (as far as I know) he'd have to `get_instance()`.  I am just ... not helping, here. :-/